# Logging out the user in laravel passport

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.5 for API development, how can we logout the user using laravel passport? Is it same as logout in web or is there any difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: @kunal revoking the access to user when user logged out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $value = $request->bearerToken();
 $id= (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
 $token= $request->user()->tokens->find($token);
 $token->revoke();
```

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-how-can-i-manually-revoke-access-token

Answer (score 5):

The above solution does not work with laravel 5.5 & passport (i tested it)
it seems to be a JWT solution.

If you're looking for the Passport way of doing it, you can do:

```
$request->user()->token()->revoke()
```

assuming the current route is using the auth:api middleware

Same sources:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passport-how-can-i-manually-revoke-access-token

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
public function logout() {
        $accessToken = Auth::user()->token();
        DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
            ->update([
                'revoked' => true
            ]);

        $accessToken->revoke();
        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
```

Comment: You just gave me the hint I was looking for, thank you @PHP Worm

Comment: @VishalParkash Awesome! This answer was posted long ago. Now there might be another way to do this in latest version.

Comment: Worm, Yes there. but your answer helped me find another good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
auth()->user()->token()->revoke();
```